# "isolinux.bin is missing or corrupt", when attempting to boot using disk in USB CD DRIVE

Tags: boot

I have an external CD drive which connects to USB. I burned 11.10 Ubuntu image to CD-R. The disk correctly shows me install page when I autoload disk within Windows 7.

When I restart to attempt to boot from disk to install Ubuntu I get the following error for a split second before I continues to boot to Windows.

"isolinux.bin is missing or corrupt".

Clearly my computer knows that this is a Linux disk in the usb cd-drive...What went wrong?

edit: I reburned another disk, same error

Comment: Perhaps... you should listen to your Computer when it tells you that the CD you made is corrupt. Use another one, A CD-RW would be better if not, then a USB stick.

Comment: I agree, most likely a bad burn. You should also check the iso - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto

Comment: I reburned another disk, same error! Any ideas?

Comment: Download the ISO again and check the MD5 check sum

Comment: OMG ppl, it's not the case. Checking MD5 sums advice is everywhere. But checksums are the same. Still can't boot into such image.

Comment: Please go through instructions on this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

Comment: I had a similar problem with 13.10 being written to a 4GB SD card. I simply ran the dd command again and ran 'sync' before ejecting it. It worked.

Comment: It was http://askubuntu.com/a/351136/79266 for me

Answer (score 4):

I have checked the MD5sum it was correct and tried two times to write the USB stick, still nothing.

After that I found this link:
http://www.hinditechy.com/isolinux-bin-missing-corrupt/

Quoting the part of that article that helped in my case:

> Boot Setting of your PC \ server – This is very important factor and i
>   have seen many users who resolved issue if above two not worked for
>   them. So you should also try below –
>
> 1. Go to BIOS settings and check Emulation Type settings
> 2. Now go to USB Flash Drive Emulation Type and select Hard Drive option. After this save changes and reboot your machine.
> 3. After reboot in the boot options you might will get hard drive option and there you need to select your USB drive.

Good luck!

Comment: This worked for me on an old Dell server!!

Answer (score 2):

You should First check the [MD5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) Before write to CD or USB. In your case The .iso you downloaded and burned on disc is faulty. You have to download .iso file again.

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone said probably a bad burn.

I recommend using a tool called Unetbootin which makes your pendrive bootable.

It is way faster then using a CD.

Comment: I don't have a pendrive with me that has enough space for the Image. I reburned the disk and the error is there still, any idea?

Comment: bad burn or a bad dvd/cd drive .... any 1 GB pendrive will do... or you can try an Ubuntu minimal iso thats only 26 mb

u can use anoter program to burn