# Ubuntu 12.10 won't boot from usb - isolinux.bin missing or corrupt

Tags: boot, usb, iso

This was an official 64-bit download from the Ubuntu site, so it's kind of sad to see even that's not working.

I made a bootable Ubuntu 12.10 USB stick with USB Image Writer (mintstick) on Linux Mint 14 Cinnamon and then shut down after ejecting the drive. When I put the drive back in and boot from it, a message shows briefly: 'isolinux.bin missing or corrupt,' before going black and booting to Mint.

I have tried Unetbootin instead of Mint's USB Image Writer but the USB drive does not show. Unetbootin has not worked for me in the past anyway whenever creating live USBs.

USB is formatted to msdos. Did not tamper w/ partitions, etc. in GParted, Disks, etc.

I have seen this issue asked once before on this website and other times across the web, but no one gives a good answer other than it's probably a bad download. If so, it's pretty disappointing because this is the official Ubuntu.com download link.

Any ideas? Are there any other alternate download mirrors besides the official one (that don't take hours to download)?

Comment: This likely relates to the bootloader not matching the kernel being loaded by **Ubuntu** 12.10. *Have you tried with **12.04 LTS**? Have you checked the download, using MD5 checksum?*

Comment: Have you done an [md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)and make sure that the USB drive is Fat32 formatted.

Comment: In case you have download problems, you can try **jdownloader** instead of looking for alternative sites, which might be risky.

Comment: i had same problem. had to convert iso to img before using dd as described here: https://www.lewan.com/blog/2012/02/10/making-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-an-apple-mac-os-x-from-an-iso

Answer (score 43):

I came across this problem(isolinux.bin missing or corrupt) recently.
The flash disk is made by `dd`, the iso file is of 12.04.3 64 bit.
I fix this by change BIOS setting: change

> USB Flash Drive Emulation Type

from 'auto' to 'hard drive'.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This solved the same issue for me when booting a Dell 1950 server.  Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't help for me.

Comment: @smwikipedia How it fails?

Comment: accuya's answer solves that error on Dell R200 for me

Comment: me too, also on a **Dell** server (T100)

Comment: Works on dell sc1430, thanks. After hitting F11 on boot you now have to click HDD instead of usb!

Comment: This was also the solution for Dell PowerEdge R410 (server)

Comment: Works on Dell Poweredge 1950

Comment: worked for me on an MSI Workstaion

Comment: Worked on Dell R710

Comment: Worked on a Dell R610 also

Comment: It's 2024 and this answer just saved me from many hours of headache on a PowerEdge 1950 that I have. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

You may need to use the following command

```
sudo dd if=linux.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

instead of

```
sudo dd if=linux.iso of=/dev/sdb1
```

Comment: Well, it wouldn't work for me as I have two partitions on USB. First for live CD/DVD, second (larger) for data.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you

Comment: Worked for CitrixHypervisor-8.2.0

Comment: Still applies in 2021. First command took 30 mins to create USB and wouldn't boot. Second approach took 5 mins and booted no issue. Bios changes had no affect.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this problem when trying to install any OS onto a Toshiba Satellite. I was finally able to get it working after disabling Fast Boot, changing from UEFI to CMS boot, and also using dd (from my kali mchine) after setting the file system type of the USB to fat32, and dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sda (after repeated failed attempts doing it on /dev/sda1)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. But the solution was rather different from the answers already given (e.g. without changing BIOS settings or using extra-tools).

I've created USB-stick via `dd` command:

```
sudo dd if=linux.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

And got during boot:

```
isolinux.bin missing or corrupt
```

The stick I've used was not blank but contained some partitions before (as far as I can remember one of them was ISO9660 because I used the stick as Live-USB for past distribution). Those partitions were **automatically mounted** by file manager (Nemo) when I plugged the stick (`dd` command haven't complained about that).

I've unmounted those partitions and wrote *linux.iso* again. And got success on next boot from the stick.

Answer (score 0):

**I recommend this as the best solution to create a live USB:**

1. Use **GParted** to create a blank USB with FAT32 format.
2. Install [MultiSystem](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/index.php?pages/install) and use it to create a **live USB** from internet or from an iso file already downloaded.

*(I've just created one from **Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit iso** file yesterday)*

Answer (score 0):

Might be a buggy BIOS ("firmware" to be more precise). Updating might help. Otherwise try UEFI mode instead of BIOS mode if available in the firmware setup. Or try a boot image that only supports BIOS systems. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am using [dd for windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd). And I encountered exactly the same issue with CentOS 7 DVD ISO. I checked the ISO checksum and it is downloaded OK.

Inspired by [this article](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey), I turn to use [Fedora Live USB Creator](https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/). It can run into the installation UI of CentOS 7. But I am having trouble with the `Error setting up base repository` issue in the installation process. According to [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/710541/centos-7-1503-getting-error-setting-up-base-repository-during-installation), it is an issue of Fedora Live USB Creator. This is so far I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

i could only boot the debian netinst iso
from an already installed GRUB
navigating to the pendrive partition:
grub>

```
ls
```

setting it as

```
root=(hdX,msdos1)
```

then load kernel

```
linux /install.amd/vmlinuz
```

then load initrd

```
initrd /install.amd/initrd.gz
```

then start it

```
boot
```

Answer (score -1):

Some folks may have just copied the ISO file to the stick hence the missing bin file. The ISO would actually need to be installed onto the USB stick via a program such as unetbootin. https://unetbootin.github.io/

Alternatively this could also be a permissions problem with ownership of the stick or the files and folders on it.

I wish you all the best of luck at sorting your issue out.

Comment: This is no longer true as most distribution ISOs are run through `isohybrid` already: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/isohybrid