# Isolinux.bin is corrupt or missing

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I have no background with linux but I wanted to give it a try.
So I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and flashed it to my newly formated 16GB USB drive and got this message.
I tried different USB drives (all of the same kind, all 16GB and all have a micro-USB on the other side to connect it to eg Android phones), the Ubuntu 18.10 version and Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa (Cinnamon). I reinstalled balena Etcher (the program I flashed the USB drives with) but it still did not work.

Comment: Make sure you search the rest of this site for that exact very common message. Then, if you still have the problem, [edit] this one and tell us what you did.

Comment: Have a look at the official Ubuntu tutorial: [Create a bootable USB stick on Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0), which suggested to use Rufus on Windows; or [Create a bootable USB stick on macOS](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0), which suggested to use Etcher on macOS. Note that the disk preparation is also important (as noted in each tutorial).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Rufus, I wanted to try that already but VirusTotal said it's problematic - I checked the version from rufus.ie
Is that the correct site?

Comment: @Bojan Yes, the URL is similarly quoted in the official tutorial and also the project page. User can also visit the project page on GitHub and download the release: https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases and the FAQ also covers the antivirus issue: https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Antivirus_X_reports_that_Rufus_contains_malware

Comment: Cool thanks - I didn't know about the GitHub for rufus. I'll check it out once I'm back on my PC

Answer (score 0):

You may need to go into your PC's BIOS setup and find the

> USB Flash Drive Emulation Type

setting and change if from "auto" to "hard drive". Worked for me on an 2012 model HP Microserver.

Also answered in [Ubuntu 12.10 won't boot from usb - isolinux.bin missing or corrupt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256739/ubuntu-12-10-wont-boot-from-usb-isolinux-bin-missing-or-corrupt) and ["isolinux.bin is missing or corrupt", when attempting to boot using disk in USB CD DRIVE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104263/isolinux-bin-is-missing-or-corrupt-when-attempting-to-boot-using-disk-in-usb)